# php explode at capital letters?

Tags: php, function

I have strings like:

```
$a = 'helloMister';
$b = 'doggyWaltz';
$c = 'bumWipe';
$d = 'pinkNips';
```

How can I explode at the capital letters? I have search on google for some time and came back with nothing!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you want to split `helloMister` into `hello` and `Mister` you can use `preg_split` to split the string at a point just before the uppercase letter by using positive lookahead assertion:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$str);
```

and if you want to split it as `hello` and `ister` you can do:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/[A-Z]/',$str);
```

Comment: if first character is already uppercase this regex generates one empty element, if you want to ommit that you can use lcfirst first: $pieces = preg_split('/.(?=[A-Z])/',lcfirst($str));

Comment: This is work fine if the first character is a lowercase, but Suppose we need to explode `RecipesActionModel` and we want only array of three elements `Receipe,Action,Model`. This solution make array with four elements which element 0 is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was researching positive lookahead assertion, and your answer helps me out a lot!

Comment: Wrap it with array_filter to get rid of any empty element.

Comment: Use this to avoid first empty element in case first element is upper case. preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', 'CamelCase', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

Answer (score 10):

Look up [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$result = preg_replace("([A-Z])", " $0", "helloMister");
print_r(explode(' ', $result));
```

hacky hack.  Just don't have spaces in your input string.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Mathew's Answer, this works perfectly,

```
$arr = preg_replace("([A-Z])", " $0", $str);
$arr = explode(" ",trim($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Further on the selected answer.

If you are dealing with acronyms in the text, it will change `OOP` to `O O P`

You can then use `preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/', $text)` to lookahead for the lower case too to capture words fully.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), it's like explode but takes a regular expression

```
preg_split('~[A-Z]~',$inputString)
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, I assume they also want the capital letter as part of the 2nd word.

Comment: Cool this is nice, does this output an array?