# php preg_split first uppercase

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Using the following code,
[php explode at capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998382/php-explode-at-capital-letters)

you can explode the string by uppercase. But how do you explode it only on the first uppercase? Say you have `helloThereMister`. I want to get `hello` `ThereMister`. I can concatenate the result from the link above, but if there is a way to skip it, then fantastic!

Thanks

Comment: Using the `limit` argument for [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: `preg_split("[A-Z]{1}", $str);`?

Comment: @putvande This will still match every capital. `{1}` doesn't limit, it just states (redundantly) that you want to find each singular capitalized alphabetical letter.

Comment: Like @MarkBaker says: `preg_split("/(?=\p{Lu})/","helloThereMister",2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTM my friend, as per documentation of [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) you have also a `$limit` parameter so the answer is:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $str, 1);
```

Comment: `(?=...)` is not needed in this case ;). It also causes great slowdowns on bigger RegEx, so please avoid it if not needed :). Furthermore +1 for the correct answer.

Comment: @pna: I'm sorry for you, but `(?=[A-Z])` was a correct pattern. Now it is false.

Answer (score 1):

look at [manual for preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split), third argument